# how to spawn objects after time delay swift 3 spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, children, removechild

I am building a shooter game. I would like to spawn a barrier every ten seconds and then delete it after 3 seconds. I think it is something like

```
                let TimeBeforeAdd = DispatchTime.now() + 5

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: TimeBeforeAdd) {

                self.Barrier.position = self.barrierPos

                self.addChild(self.Barrier)

                self.barrierAdded = true





    }

    if barrierAdded == true {

        let RemoveTime = DispatchTime.now() + 3

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: RemoveTime) {

            self.Barrier.removeFromParent()

            self.barrierAdded = false

        }


    }
```

but when it runs after ten seconds I get an error saying it added multiple instances of "Barrier" thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very cool idea with the dispatch timers. However, there is a *much* easier way! Here you go:

```
// Inside of your gamescene:
func spawnThingEveryTenSecondsThenDeleteAfterThree() {

  func spawnShootyThing()   { /* input your code here */ }
  func despawnShootyThing() { /* input your code here */ }

  let wait10  = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10)
  let wait3   = SKAction.wait(forDuration:  3)
  let spawn   = SKAction.run { spawnShootyThing() }
  let despawn = SKAction.run { despawnShootyThing() }

  let action = SKAction.sequence([wait10, spawn, wait3, despawn])

  // If you don't want this action to run forever, then remove this action!
  let forever = SKAction.repeatForever(action)

  self.run(forever)
}
```